# Is there a kaddish sheet with the differences in nusach highlighted?

Tags: product-recommendation, kaddish, nuschaot

Sometimes we have a case of [Saying kaddish when davening in a minyan that isn't your nusach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49021/saying-kaddish-when-davening-in-a-minyan-that-isnt-your-nusach?rq=1). Very often in fact, i'll hear up to 3 nuschaot of kaddish being recited at once.

In cases like this, it's easy to get confused about when to wait for people saying something "extra".

Does anyone know of a chart that prints kaddish in multiple nuschaot with the differences highlighted?

Comment: Sounds like something someone could put together from scratch pretty quickly. There aren't *that* many variants

Comment: Yep, i figured i'd put this out there to see if anyone has done it already, and if not, i'll do it myself.

Comment: Note it's not always appropriate to wait at the location of the insertion. It may be better to wait earlier to avoid a hefsek at relevant parts

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like you have a bit of a project. I was about to ask about the real necessity for this, but, perhaps, someone who attends the "minyan factory" in Yerushalayim may need this. Am I assuming, correctly, that you live in Israel or regularly attend a minyan factory?

Comment: As an aside, it's probably not appropriate for there to be different versions of Kaddish said at the same Minyan.

Comment: @salm also multiple kaddishs at the same time... but אין חכמה ואין עצה ואין תבונה נגד האבלים

Comment: @Salmononius2 - I am pretty sure that is true. Isn't it halacha that one must say kaddish and kedusha according to the nusach of the shul? But then again, if this is a "minyan factory" like DanF mentioned, then...

Comment: @ezra, Kedushah is easier: you only **need** to say the pesukim. The other bits are just gravy for the ש"ץ.

Answer (score 1):

[Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9) includes an in-article chart, with most differences highlighted.

Common portions highlighted.

> יִתְגַּדַּל וְיִתְקַדַּשׁ שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא
>
> בְּעָלְמָא דִּי בְרָא כִרְעוּתֵהּ וְיַמְלִיךְ מַלְכוּתֵהּ
>
> **ספרדים וחסידים:** וְיַצְמַח פֻּרְקָנֵהּ וִיקָרֵב מְשִׁיחֵהּ
> **לפי נוסח תימן מוסיפים:** וְיִפְרוֹק עַמֵיהּ
>
> בְּחַיֵּיכוֹן וּבְיוֹמֵיכוֹן וּבְחַיֵּי דְכָל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל,
> בַּעֲגָלָא וּבִזְמַן קָרִיב וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן
>
> יְהֵא שְׁמֵהּ רַבָּא מְבָרַךְ לְעָלַם וּלְעָלְמֵי עָלְמַיָּא.
>
> יִתְבָּרַךְ [**תימנים:** אמן] וְיִשְׁתַּבַּח וְיִתְפָּאַר וְיִתְרוֹמַם,
>
> וְיִתְנַשֵּׂא וְיִתְהַדָּר וְיִתְעַלֶּה וְיִתְהַלָּל שְׁמֵהּ
> דְּקֻדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא לְעֵלָּא [**איטליא:** ולעלא] מִן כָּל
> בִּרְכָתָא שִׁירָתָא תֻּשְׁבְּחָתָא וְנֶחָמָתָא דַּאֲמִירָן בְּעָלְמָא
>
> וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> **לפי מרבית קהילות הספרדים:** תִּתְקַבַּל צְלוֹתָנָא וּבָעוּתָנָא עִם צְלוֹתְהוֹן וּבָעוּתְהוֹן דְּכָל-בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל, קֳדָם אֲבוּנָא
> דְבִשְׁמַיָּא (וְאַרְעָא), וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> **לפי תימן בלדי:** תִּתְקַבַּל צְלוֹתְכוֹן וְתִתְעֲבֵיד בְּעוּתְכוֹן וּצְלוֹתְהוֹן וּבְעוּתְהוֹן דְּכָל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל קֳדָם אֲבוּנָא
> דְּבִשְׁמַיָּא
>
> **לפי תימן שאמי:** תִּתְקַבַּל צְלוֹתְכוֹן וְתִתְעֲבֵיד בְּעוּתְכוֹן עם צְלוֹתְהוֹן וּבְעוּתְהוֹן דְּכָל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל קֳדָם אֲבוּנָא
> דְּבִשְׁמַיָּא, וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> **לפי יתר הנוסחים:** תִּתְקַבַּל צְלוֹתְהוֹן וּבָעוּתְהוֹן דְּכָל בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל קֳדָם אֲבוּהוֹן דִּי בִשְׁמַיָּא וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> **כאשר אומרים קדיש דרבנן מוסיפים:**
>
> עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל וְעַל רַבָּנָן וְעַל תַּלְמִידֵיהוֹן וְעַל כָּל
> תַּלְמִידֵי תַלְמִידֵיהוֹן.
>
> **נוסח אשכנז ונוסח ספרד:** וְעַל כָּל מָאן דְּעָסְקִין בְּאוֹרַיְתָא  ֿ
>
> **נוסח איטליה:** דְּיָתְבִין דְּעָסְקִין בְּאוֹרַיְתָא קַדִּשְׁתָּא
>
> **נוסח הספרדים:** דְּעָסְקִין בְּאוֹרַיְתָא קַדִּשְׁתָּא
>
> **תימן בלדי:** דְּעָסְקִין בְּאוֹרַיְתָא
>
> דִּי בְאַתְרָא הָדֵין וְדִי בְכָל אָתָר וְאָתָר, יְהֵא לָנָא וּלְהוֹן
>
> וּלְכוֹן שְׁלָמָא רַבָּאחִנָּא וְחִסְדָּא וְרַחֲמֵי
>
> **האשכנזים מוסיפים:** וְחַיֵּי אֲרִיכֵי וּמְזוֹנֵי רְוִיחֵי וּפֻרְקָנָא
>
> **נוסח איטליה:** מִן קֳדָם אֱלָהָנָא מָארֵי שְׁמַיָּא וְאַרְעָא
>
> **נוסח הספרדים:** מִן קֳדָם מָארֵי שְׁמַיָּא וְאַרְעָא
>
> **נוסח אשכנז ונוסח ספרד:** מִן קֳדָם אֲבוּהוֹן דִּי בִשְׁמַיָּא
>
> **נוסח תימן:** מִן קֳדָם אֲבוּנָא דְּבִשְׁמַיָא
>
> וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> **מכאן ואילך מוסיפים בכל סוגי הקדיש למעט חצי קדיש**
>
> יְהֵא שְׁלָמָא רַבָּא מִן שְׁמַיָּא
>
> **נוסח אשכנז:** וְחַיִּים עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל
>
> **נוסח ספרד ונוסח איטליה:** וְחַיִּים טוֹבִים עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל
>
> **נוסח הספרדים:** חַיִּים וְשָׁבָע וִישׁוּעָה וְנֶחָמָה וְשֵׁיזָבָא וּרְפוּאָה וּגְאֻלָּה וּסְלִיחָה וְכַפָּרָה וְרֵוַח וְהַצָּלָה לָנוּ
> וּלְכָל עַמּוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל
>
> **תימן בלדי:** וְסִיַּעְתָּא וּפֻרְקָנָא וּרְוַחָא וְחִנָּא וְחִסְדָּא וְרַחֲמֵי עֲלֵיכוֹן וַעֲלַנָא וְעַל כָּל קְהָלְהוֹן דְּכָל בֵּית
> יִשְׂרָאֵל לְחַיִּים וּלְשָׁלוֹם
>
> וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> עוֹשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם בִּמְרוֹמָיו הוּא בְּרַחֲמָיו יַעֲשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם
> עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל
>
> **ברוב הנוסחים מסיימים כדלקמן:** וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן.
>
> **בנוסח תימן מסיימים כדלקמן:** וִינַחֲמֵנוּ בְּצִיוֹן וְיִבְנֶה בְּרַחֲמָיו אֶת יְרוּשָׁלָיִם בְּחַיֵּינוּ וּבְיָמֵינוּ בְּקָרוֹב
> אָמֵן וְאָמֵן.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct. In my limited experience, at least, Ashkenazim don't say לָנָא in קדיש דרבנן.

Comment: @msh210, I believe I've heard it, although על ישראל varies on a pretty much siddur-to-siddur level in Nusach Ashkenaz, in my experience.